# Custom video control buttons for mobile friendly site -- "play" not working

Tags: javascript, ios, html, video

I’m working on a website that has different videos on top of one another for a class. Each video is from a different perspective of a character and the user has the option to choose which video to show from a button bar on the bottom of the page. I have my own custom buttons to play, pause, rewind, fastforward, etc so to keep all the other videos in sync.

This website has to work on mobile and right now I can’t seem to get my custom buttons to play the video. I hosted the videos and all the elements show on the page, and you can see the video outline with the typical grey play symbol overlay. The video doesn’t start when my play button is pressed, only when the video itself is pressed. When the video is pressed, it does the typical mobile full screen with black surround -- basically leaving the webpage. The buttons and interactivity work just fine on all browsers from a computer, just don’t know how to make it totally mobile friendly. This is my first major HTML5/javascript project. Is there something I'm missing?

This is the javascript concerning the buttons I made:

```
var video = document.querySelector('#one'),
        beginningButton = document.querySelector('#beginning'),
        rewindButton = document.querySelector('#rewind'),
        playButton = document.querySelector('#play'),
        pauseButton = document.querySelector('#pause'),
        fastforwardButton = document.querySelector('#fastforward'),
        endButton = document.querySelector('#end'),
        video1Button = document.querySelector('#toggle_video_1'),
        video2Button = document.querySelector('#toggle_video_2'),
        position = document.querySelector('#position'),
        ready = false,
        controls = document.querySelector('#controls'),
        scrub = document.querySelector('#scrub');

    // Button events
    addEvent( video1Button, 'click', function () {
      $( video ).toggle();
      if( this.value == "video 1 Off"){
        this.value = "video 1 On"; 
      }
      else{ 
        this.value = "video 1 Off"; 
      }
    });

    /* repeat several times for each of the videos ... */

    // video events
    addEvent( beginningButton, 'click', function() {
      video.currentTime = 0;
      video2.currentTime = 0;
    });

    addEvent( rewindButton, 'mousedown', function() {
      video.playbackRate = -2.0;
      video2.playbackRate = -2.0;
    });

    addEvent( rewindButton, 'mouseup', function() {
      video.playbackRate = 1.0;
      video2.playbackRate = 1.0;
    });

    addEvent( playButton, 'click', function() {
      if ( ready ) {
        if( video.paused ){
          video2.currentTime = video.currentTime;
          video.play();
        }
      }
    });

    addEvent( pauseButton, 'click', function () {
      if ( ready ) {
        if ( video.paused ) {
          if ( video.ended ) {
            video.currentTime = 0;
            video2.currentTime = 0;
          }
        } else {
          video.pause();
          video2.currentTime = video.currentTime;
        }
      }
    });

    addEvent( fastforwardButton, 'mousedown', function() {
      video.playbackRate = 2.0;
      video2.playbackRate = 2.0;
    });

    addEvent( fastforwardButton, 'mouseup', function() {
      video.playbackRate = 1.0;
      video2.playbackRate = 1.0;
    });

    addEvent( endButton, 'click', function() {
      video.currentTime = video.duration;
      video2.currentTime = video.duration;
    });

    addEvent( video, 'play', function () {
      video2.play();
    });

    addEvent( video, 'pause', function () {
      video2.pause();
    })
```

Comment: could you give us a live-demo of the page? or a jsfiddle of the problem? code in any form would be helpful ;)

Comment: Sorry, just added javascript of the custom buttons

Comment: That barely shows anything useful without HTML etc... You should check out this guide: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask   The only thing I can think of is you're missing touch events... add jquery mobile and events for touchup, etc.